What's the difference between using ALL vs VALUES in MAXX table parameter?
MAXX(<table>,<expression>,[<variant>])

What's the difference between using ALL(Product['Name']) vs VALUES(Product['Name']) in the above DAX?

VALUES will return only the value of product names in the current filter context (i.e. a subset). ALL will return all of them.

Unless for example this is used in calculate, and the second parameter to CALCULATE is something like REMOVEFILTERS.?

Yes, in that case they'd behave the same.
